# Looping through and showing images in laravel blade, changing old angular code

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I'm trying to change an angular `repeat` that was being done on images on our website (in laravel). I'm removing angular from everything and trying to get it all done in laravel loops in the blade.

I successfully changed everything to work with our controller and the image names are being collected, but on the front end it just shows the image names not the images themselves.

Here's the original (working code) from angular:

```
<li ng-repeat="i in x.image_names track by $index"><a href="/imagelib/mediums/{{::i.split(',')[0] }}" target=_blank><img ng-src="/imagelib/mediums/{{::i.split(',')[0] }}" style="width: 100%; height: auto;" /></a><span class="uk-text-center" style="padding: 0 0 5px;">{{ ::i.split(',')[1] }}</span></li>
```

And here's my new code (showing correct image names, but only the name not the actual image):

```
@foreach ($pgroup->image_names as $image_name)
<li><a href="/imagelib/mediums/{{ $image_name }}" target=_blank><img ng-src="/imagelib/mediums/{{ $image_name }}" style="width: 100%; height: auto;" /></a><span class="uk-text-center" style="padding: 0 0 5px;">{{ $image_name }}</span></li>
@endforeach
```

Am I overlooking something in my conversion from Angular to Laravel that would cause the images to not show up?

Comment: `ng-` functions are pure angular/javascript. You need to change the src attribute to be just `src`

Comment: Thanks I definitely overlooked that. However, still same issue

Comment: Can you post the generated source code of the browser? It looks like the image name might be wrong, considering the original code was splitting the file name on the first comma.

Comment: Ah, yes you're right. It's posting this as the file name ```4541_berryhill_sofa_taupe.jpg,Taupe``` the image name and the color it's associated with. Is there a way to split it the same way?

Comment: Yes, you can extract the name like this `substr($image_name, 0, strpos($image_name, ','))`.

Comment: but can I do that right there in the blade template?

Comment: Yes, Blade is PHP after all. But I recommend you placing it in an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) function inside your model.

Comment: Perfect, got it! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to replace `ng-src` with `src` in the `img` tag:

```
<img src="/imagelib/mediums/{{ $image_name }}" />
```

Then, since `$image_name` contains a CSV, you need to strip the image name. You can do this like:

```
substr($image_name, 0, strpos($image_name, ','));
```

If you want to extract the second value from `$image_name`, you can do it like:

```
substr($image_name, strpos($image_name, ',') + 1);
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! And if I wanted the word AFTER the comma, would I just change the strpos?

Comment: Yes, you can do it like this `substr($image_name, strpos($image_name, ',') + 1)`. Added to the answer.